# Error integrating Authorize.net payment gateway: MerchantAuthenticationType not found

Tags: php, authorize.net

I am integrating Authorize.net payment gateway in my project in php. But here I am facing this error.

> Fatal error: Class 'net\authorize\api\contract\v1\MerchantAuthenticationType' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/payment/charge-credit-card.php on line 9

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use net\authorize\api\contract\v1 as AnetAPI;
use net\authorize\api\controller as AnetController;
define("AUTHORIZENET_LOG_FILE","phplog");
// Common setup for API credentials
$merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType()
```

I have downloaded PHP-SDK from github and did as they say.

Comment: You may want to show some code in order to receive more answers..

Comment: Looks like you do not have all required dependencies in place. but there is nothing specific we can say without you providing more information about the specific situation, especially the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType() in this line i am getting error.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing: require 'vendor/autoload.php';

With:  require 'autoload.php';

I am an amateur and I had used composer and it was doing weird things.  I had to find and move a bunch of files to get the whole thing working.  The hardest part was finding the right autoload.php.

I hope it helps...newbie here so...